# Python: 'ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar' when using predict function on differential private RF Classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When implementing a differential private Random Forest Classifier then functions predict and predict_proba failed with the following error `"ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar"`

I'm using a dataset with both numeric and categorical columns that were already pre processed and when applied the same process to the Logistic regression classifier it works.

```
np.random.seed(seed)

from diffprivlib.models import RandomForestClassifier as  DPRF # DP version of classifier

clf3 = DPRF(epsilon = 3.0, data_norm=7.89,random_state=seed)
clf3.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf3.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

y_probs = clf3.predict_proba(X_test)
roc_score = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_probs[:,1], multi_class='ovo')
print('ROC AUC Score: %f' %roc_score)
```

[image]

The `X_train` is a pandas dataframe with shape (65548, 26)

Comment: Can you please paste complete error traceback?

Comment: Better not to include images of code/error messages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.